# Number of Purchased Item on Each Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, ce-1.9.0.1, quantity

I want to display the number of purchased item/s on a certain product. 
I did use this code:

```
$resultQuantity = $this->getQuantityPurchase($_product);
$resultQuantity[0];
```

But it displays nothing. What should I do?
Could I use the Product ID for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = 123; // enter your product ID here
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $produt->getSku())
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
    ->getFirstItem();

echo (int)$product->ordered_qty;
```

Comment: I have tried your code and I got same results for all products.

Comment: update your tried  code in question?

Comment: yes I did update it.

Comment: updated answer and tested too..

Comment: it is working but it includes the one which are pending for payment.

Comment: it work like number of time ordered. it is not concern with order status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34344/discussion-between-alen-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by getting the product sold collection

```
/** @var Mage_Report_Model_Mysql4_Product_Sold_Collection **/
$report = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection');
```

You can set a date range or other criteria if you want. Once you have your collection just iterate over it, something like this:

```
foreach ($report AS $product) {
echo $product->getOrderedQty();}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Mage::getResourceModel('report/product_sold_collection'). What are the filter that can be used on this report?

Comment: you can use product attribute filters like $report->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $produt->getSku())

Comment: I see. I will give it a try.

Comment: I am getting an error regarding the Filter.

Comment: What type of error your are getting on apply filter.you can set date range like $report->setDateRange($from, $to)

Comment: you can also  $report->addFieldToFilter( 'your_filed', '1' );